# Save previous page and use next button to link other page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i have create a model name eforms

```
class Eform < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :account_name, :employee_id, :life_cycle, :project_name

  has_many :sprints 

end
```

and other model name sprints

```
class Sprint < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :Sprint_name, :eform_id

  has_many :efforts 

  belongs_to :eform

end
```

here i filled the content of eform eform_id which is primary key

but i want to link that eform_id which is foreign key in sprint by using submit button or next button it should redirect to sprint page by saving eform page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model structure is totally wrong - you're using `attr_accessible` in Rails 4 - this is depreciated & replaced with `strong params`

Apart from not knowing what you want to achieve, you need to look at how you're capturing & using the data in your Rails app. Firstly, `attr_accessible` will not save your attributes - only keep them for the duration of the object

I would recommend [reading up on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) to get a better idea of how to do this